# Able to use rosjava and roscore together?

Tags: roscore, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Sorry another question as I dig through the documentation - am I able to use rosjava to create a publishing node and have the C++ roscore/rest of ros pick it up?

Reason I'm asking is because I've already got some parsing code in Java that I can reuse, but will prog the rest of my system in C++.

Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32445/able-to-use-rosjava-and-roscore-together?/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2012-04-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the ROS publish subscribe system allows you to publish in one language, but subscribe in others.  This is useful for having high performance nodes in C++ but high complexity nodes in Python.  Since you already have functionality in Java, it's perfect to use Java to parse and then send it to another node in another language for processing.

You should note that there isn't a requirement to have a 'roscore' for each language.  A roscore is a program that acts as a control hub to tell subscribers where to ask for data from a topic.  These only interact with other nodes over the network.  For example, it is NOT necessary to launch the python roscore for python nodes and launch the Java roscore if you have nodes in Java.  You only need to have one roscore running.

More information on that, see these links.  [Concepts](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Concepts#ROS_Computation_Graph_Level)  [Master](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Master)

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-04-24**:
Chad - thanks for the info - I was hoping that'd be the case

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-04-25**:
You should note that although there isn't a roscore for every language, there is one for Java. It is interchangeable with the official roscore in Python.

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2012-04-25**:
Thanks Damon.  I tried to clarify this in an edit.  I meant to say that you aren't forced to run the Java roscore to run Java nodes.

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-04-25**:
Cool - figured that'd be the case. Once I get Eclipse to work (Found the tuts on that) hope to have a basic node connecting to my existing svr over the weekend. Cheers M